# What would be the Growth Rate of the following function

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

What would be the growth rate of the following function in terms of Big O notation??

```
f (n) = Comb(1000,n) for n = 0,1,2,…


int Comb(int m, int n)
{
    int pracResult = 1;
    int i;

    if (m > n/2) m = n-m;

    for (i=1; i<= m; i++)
    {
        pracResult *= n-m+i;
        pracResult /= i;
        practicalCounter++;
    }

    return pracResult;

}
```

Recursive:

```
int combRecursive (int m, int n)
{
    recursiveCounter++;
    if (n == m) return 1;
    if (m == 1) return n;
    return combRecursive(n-1, m) + combRecursive(n-1, m-1);

}
```

I would guess n^2??? I am probably wrong though... I have always struggled to figure out how efficient things are...

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I take back my words. If what you have written is correct the your function runs in  O(1).

Comment: need more info on Comb()

Comment: I apologize. I will update the question shortly.

Comment: @JLott  : Are you 100% sure you are using variable m and n in the correct order ? 
You pass n as second param , but the first param is named n.

Comment: Good catch. For my code it doesn't really matter, but I can see where it would be confusing. Updating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `O(1)`.

By definition, `f(n) = O(g(n))` if there exists a `c` such that for all `n`, `f(n) <= c*g(n)`

Let `c` = `Comb(1000,500)`

For all `n`, `Comb(1000, n) < c * 1`. Hence `Comb(1000, n) = O(1)`

Comment: YOu really think this is the answer she was looking for ? :)

Comment: @Ajeet, I think it is the answer to the question posed. Surprisingly often, people ask questions not actually expecting the correct answer. Sometimes this even leads them to accept incorrect answers. This happens often in politics, too.

Comment: That is impossible I feel... This function basically finds the number of combinations given m and n.. I can tell by how my code runs that it does not find it on the first go around because I put a counter in. However, the way I did it is much more efficient than if you were to do it recursively.

Comment: @JLott, your code goes through that loop `m` times, with a maximum of `n/2`. So it is certainly more than once, but always less than `500` (which is still O(1)). Anyway, I think you want to know how much computation you are doing, not what value of the function is. That's a different question. Even there, you should be careful to not ask the question with a fixed limit.

Comment: @JLott: if you want to model the execution time of your program, you probably need to take into account the size of the numbers, since they will get very big. If you did that, and you asked what the execution time of `Comb(n, n/2)` was, you'd probably get `O(n^2)`, as you originally suggested.

Comment: I was thinking about this and I am actually looking for the growth rate of the function.. Wouldn't that be the same regardless of the method used??

Comment: @JLott: Any function with a maximum value is O(1). C(1000,n) has a maximum value. C(n,2) is O(n^2); C(n,3) is O(n^3); and so on. C(n,n/2) is O(2^n). But C(1000,n) is O(1). Remember the definition: f(n) is in O(g(n)) if there is some constant c such that for every n, f(n) < c*g(n) (technically, it could be for every n greater than some other constant d, but that doesn't really matter).

Answer (score 0):

For n = 1 to 2000 there will operations proportional to n

For all n > 2000,   total operations are constant.

**Hence  function complexity is O (1)**

And I have to tell you that you gotta read some books. :)
Data-structure and algorithm by Sahni is very light read.
Algorithms by Knuth is very heavy, but amongst best.

Comment: Yeah I am actually very surprised haha.

Comment: And thanks, I will look into it :) Algorithms have never really been my thing. I am a trial and error type person when it comes to them hahaha.